# How to store a network context that you want to restore in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to restore an initial(back to its first state) context of turtles and link after killing one turtle.
I have been trying the solution from http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html, but somehow it doesn't work.
Below is my code

```
to cycle
    if Measure = "Efficiency of network" 
      [ ;store node and link
        nw:set-context turtles with [ shape = "circle" ]  links with [ color = blue ]
        show map sort nw:get-context
        set old-turtles item 0 nw:get-context
        show old-turtles
        set old-links item 1 nw:get-context
        show old-links  
        ;start process
        process-performance     
      ]
end

to process-performance

  if NumberOfNodes = 1 
  [file-open "1node.txt"  
    while [not file-at-end?]
    [
      ;calculate initial performance value
      set initial nw:mean-path-length
      show initial

      let nodeseq read-from-string (word "[" file-read-line "]")
      show item 0 nodeseq
      ask turtle (item 0 nodeseq) [ die ]
      update-plots

      ;calculate new performance value
      set final nw:mean-path-length
      show final
      set result (1 - (final / initial)) * 100
      show result

      nw:set-context old-turtles old-links
      show map sort nw:get-context

    ]    
    file-close
]
end
```

I have been using "nw:set-context old-turtles old-links" in the documentation from netlogo but it seems that the original turtle and link context I store in "old-turtles old-links" will be purposefully altered no matter how I store them. I am thinking if [die] function alter the agent-set stored? The old-turtles and old-links are progressively smaller in size as I kill the node. I did not store the renewed context of the nw back to old-turtles and old-links.

Or does anyone have other ways in storing the old agent-set and link and restoring back to its original network structure?

Thanks for reading through.

Answer (score 1):

Killing a turtle does indeed remove it from all agentsets, so restoring the context won't bring it back. You might try removing the turtle from the context rather than killing it. You could hide the turtle and its links to reproduce the visuals of killing it as well. This would be something like:

```
...
let target-turtle turtle (item 0 nodeseq)
ask target-turtle [
  hide-turtle
  ask my-links [ hide-link ]
]
nw:with-context (remove turtle (item 0 nodeseq) old-turtles) old-links [
  update-plots

  ;calculate new performance value
  set final nw:mean-path-length
  show final
  set result (1 - (final / initial)) * 100
  show result
]
...
```

This way, the turtle is removed from the context for the purpose of your calculations, but not killed, so its structural information is remembered. [`nw:with-context`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#with-context) handles storing and restoring the context for you, but this code works just as well without it (you just have to restore the context yourself).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and your verification on the killing of turtle which will also remove it from all agentset. Quite an interesting property. I will try with "hide" function later. Currently, I am using a very brute force method to restore back all my node and link.